# SQL select and insert if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, case

I want to make an sql query which can insert into table1. This table references table2 with the table2_id foreign key.

my sql looks like this so far:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (table1_id, name, date, table2_id) 
VALUES (1, "somename", "29.04.2014", (SELECT id FROM table 2 WHERE table2.name = "BOB")  )
```

I also want to insert values into table2 if it cannot find the table2.name and then insert the key for this into table1.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Edited for easier reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `insert . . . select` rather than `insert . . . values`:

```
INSERT INTO hovedenhet (organisasjonsnummer, navn, stiftelsesdato, registreringsdatoEnhetsregisteret, organisasjonsform_id) 
    SELECT 813550202, 'SAMEIET SCHWEIGAARDSGATE 21-23', '10.01.2014', '29.04.2014', id
    FROM organisasjonsformhovedenhet oh
    WHERE oh.organisasjonsform = 'BOB';
```

Your original query will insert the row with a `NULL` value for the last column, if there is no match.  This will not insert anything in that case.

Comment: Change `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid "duplicate key error".